# List of Appendixes with memior and \include

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, memoir, include

I am trying to do 2 final things for my dissertation and I can not figure out how to do them. I have looked at all the other answers to this question and I can't seem to get anything to work from what I've researched. I apologize that this may be a repeat question but again I haven't found a solution.

I have a main Latex file that I am including all my chapters and appendixes in. I need to generate a list of appendixes (like a list of figures) and also I need to remove the appendixes from my toc.

This is the basic structure:

```
    \documentclass[12pt, oneside]{memoir}

    \begin{document}
    %%%% Front Matter %%%% 
    \frontmatter 
    \include{Front_Matter}

    %%%% Chapters %%%% 
    \mainmatter 
    \include{Introduction}
    ...        
    \include{Conclusion}

    %%%% Appendixes %%%% 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendixes}
    \part*{Appendixes}

    \appendix
    \include{Appendix1}
    \include{Appendix2}

    \end{document}
```

I need to keep the reference to where the appendixes begin in the toc, which is why I have the \part* and the \addcontentsline. I need the appendix parts (section, subsection) removed from the TOC and a separate List of Appendixes to go after my lists of tables and figures.

The appendixes are structured like:

```
    \chapter{Appendix 1}

    \section{Section 1}

    ...text...

    \subsection{Subsection 1}

    ...text...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: where should the appendix list be located? It can be done with a little extra work. Also are the appendices the very last ting in the doc or does, say the bibliography come after it?

Comment: @daleif the two appendixes listed above should be at the end of the dissertation before the references. These are technical appendixes for data and other items that span all the chapters. I do have an appendix at the end of each chapter for extra figures (I used the \subappendices for those). Not sure if that matters or not.

Comment: Ok, that complicates things a little, but not much. I'll see what I can come up with. `memoir` has a feature where we can insert hooks into the `toc` file. This hooks can then be used to enable and disable various stuff

Comment: BTW: see `\appendixpage` in the manual, I'd also recommend having a pointer to the appendices in the main toc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution to this problem. I think I've answered it here before, just did not bother to search for it.

The idea is to use `\cftinserthook` to create trigger points in the `.toc` file. This triggers or hooks can then run code at that particular place in the `.toc` which we can use to alter how the TOC is formated.

So basically we enclose the appendix section with a pair of hooks plus add a hook at the start for later. Then in the normal state ask it to ignore the appendix section.

For making the appendix list, we locally redefined the hook code to do something else, and then rerun `\tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

% normal settings for the A,B,C hooks
% A does nothing by default
% B disable the toc from this point
\cftinsertcode{B}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}}
% in C we'd like the normal tocdepth
\newcounter{normaltocdepth}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \setcounter{normaltocdepth}{\value{tocdepth}}
}
\cftinsertcode{C}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\value{normaltocdepth}}}

% ned we build the macro for the list of appendencies
\newcommand\listofappendencies{
  \begingroup % keep changes local
  % the idea is to just use \tableofcontents* again, but with
  % different values for the hooks
  \cftinsertcode{A}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}}
  % or what ever explicit depth you want
  \cftinsertcode{B}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\value{normaltocdepth}}}
  % all after the C hook is ignored
  \cftinsertcode{C}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}}
  % different name for the list
  \renewcommand\contentsname{List of Appendencies}
  \tableofcontents% add * if not wanted in main toc
  \endgroup
}



\settocdepth{subsubsection}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents*

\cftinserthook{toc}{A}


\chapter{Test}

\section{T1}

\subsection{T11}

\subsubsection{T111}


\appendix
\appendixpage


\listofappendencies

\cftinserthook{toc}{B}


\chapter{App 1}

\section{T1}

\subsection{T11}

\subsubsection{T111}


\chapter{App 2}

\section{T1}

\subsection{T11}

\subsubsection{T111}



\cftinserthook{toc}{C}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A} Test
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution worked great. Thank you very much for your help. You've saved me a lot of hassle. Also, I tried to up vote your answer but my rep isn't high enough for it to count sadly :/